# NavBar Bootstrap abrindo errado link em pontos do site

Tags: html, menu, layout-responsivo, bootstrap-4, nav-bar

no meu site tenho um menu que adiciono com header.php em determinadas partes do site, home e seus links simbolicos. o problema esta quando passa do menu horizontal para aquele botão que se abre responsivo. se eu estiver em um nos links internos e clicar no botão ele vai abrir o menu da home e não o do link interno( simbolico) que estou em questão.

Index.php

```
   esse é o principal que ele sempre abre.
   <div class="wrapper">
    <?php
        include("header.php");
    ?>....
   <div id="qualidade-page" class="wrapper">
    <?php
    include("header.php");
    ?>...
 <div id="contato-page" class="wrapper">
    <?php
    include("header.php");
    ?>....
```

header.php

```
 <div class="main-header">
   <a href="index.php" class="logo">
     <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
     <span class="title">titulo </span>
</a>
    <p class="title-lateral>subtitulo</p>
   <div class="menu">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php#produtos-page" >Produtos</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link "  href="index.php#qualidade-page">Qualidade</a>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php#contato-page" >Contato</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.menu{
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    height: 60%;
}

.nav-item{
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;

}
.nav-item a{
    color:#5b5454;
}
```

Comment: Ficou um pouco confuso de entender... Aparentemente vc tem uma navbar apenas, mas chama a mesma Navbar em três lugares diferentes... pq faz isso? Vc fica com 3Navs iguais ao mesmo tempo na mesma página é isso mesmo?

Comment: psé seria isso. na real depois eu percebi que não seria muito inteligente isso. saberia me dizer como eu faço para ter apenas um navbar e ele acompanhar o scroll ou os links simbolicos, no caso ficar sempre no topo do link simbolico.

Comment: Primeiro faça apenas 1 include desse Menu, depois na documentação tem sua resposta https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement . As âncoras devem ser tipo `href="#produtos-page"` já que o ID correspondente está na mesma página, então não precisa do home.php antes. Essa resposta em um Menu de Bootstrap que fica fixo no topo, no seu caso basta remover a div azul e ele já vai ficar sempre no top https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387949/barra-de-navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-bootstrap/387960#387960

Comment: é que eu estava usando o mesmo nav em outra pagina especifica, ai para ele redirecionar precisa do index da frente. Isso seria uma má prática ?

Comment: Nessa caso não é má prática não.