# Menu que se fixa após scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom dia!

Como posso fazer o efeito suave de fixação do menu ao rolar a página como nessa:
https://overwatchleague.com/pt-br/

Comment: Se vc estiver usando **Bootstrap** essa resposta pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387949/barra-de-navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-bootstrap/387960#387960

Answer (score 0):

Bem por partes...
No HTML precisas adicionar o elemento que será a navegação.

```
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>
```

Quase toda a magia está nos estilos, que deverão ser algo assim:

```
 /* Estilos do header */
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

/* Conteúdo */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* Esta classe é adicionada em JS quando o header chega à posição de scroll */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Hack para prevenir movimentos bruscos nos elementos da página quando o header fica fixo */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

E finalmente o JS:

```
// Quando user fizer scroll executar a myFuntion
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Adicionar a classe sticky ao header quando chega à posição de scroll e remover quando sai dessa posição.
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```